# How to pick a timezone based on UTC offset?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

i've got a silly problem. I'm parsing Facebook user data, and I get the timezone as a number:

> timezone: The user's timezone offset from UTC

For me (`'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'`) it's -3.

Now, how can I convert that number to a `pytz.timezone`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

There's not a 1:1 correspondence, so there's no way to do it without making some assumptions that are bound to be invalid.

You can create your own [`tzinfo`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) class that encodes the offset directly without trying to tie it back to a zone.

Comment: As an alternative to subclassing `tzinfo`, you can use ``dateutil.tz.tzoffset``: https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-8bf499d888b70bc300c6c8820dc123326197c00f

Answer (score 2):

As [@Mark Ransom said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11657463/4279), multiple `pytz.timezone` may have the same UTC offset at a given date. You could print the mapping for a particular date:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime

import pytz # $ pip install pytz

dt = datetime.now(pytz.utc) # current time in UTC
zone_names = defaultdict(list)
for tz in pytz.common_timezones:
    zone_names[dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone(tz)).utcoffset()].append(tz)

for offset, zone in sorted(zone_names.items()):
    print("%.1f %s" % (offset.total_seconds() / 3600, zone))
# -> -11.0 ['Pacific/Midway', 'Pacific/Niue', 'Pacific/Pago_Pago']
# ...
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use [tzinfo.tzname](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo.tzname) to get the zone name.

Comment: But I need to have a timezone for that.