# convert string 'GMT+5:30' to Time Zone (like Aisa/Kolkata) without checking datetime.datetime.now() in python

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

convert string 'GMT+5:30' to Time Zone (like Aisa/Kolkata) without checking datetime.datetime.now() in python

```
now = datetime.datetime.astimezone(Time_Zone).tzname()  # current time
print(now)
print(type(now))
utc_offset = datetime.timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)  # +5:30
print(utc_offset)
for tz in map(pytz.timezone, pytz.all_timezones_set):
    if (now.astimezone(tz).utcoffset() == utc_offset):
        print(tz.zone)
```

Comment: Is there any problem with the code? does it throw any error?

Comment: related: [How to pick a timezone based on UTC offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657273/how-to-pick-a-timezone-based-on-utc-offset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find matching timezones for a given UTC offset you must specify a date since the UTC offset of timezones changes over time and they might have DST during certain periods. Timezones and DST originate from political decisions so it's not as easy as hacking together a Python script.

Here's an example to find timezones with UTC+5:30 using `dateutil`:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.tz import gettz
from dateutil.zoneinfo import get_zonefile_instance

offset, match_offset = int(60*60*5.5), []

for z in get_zonefile_instance().zones:
    off = datetime.datetime.now(tz=gettz(z)).utcoffset()
    if int(off.total_seconds()) == offset:
        match_offset.append(z)

print(match_offset)
# ['Asia/Calcutta', 'Asia/Colombo', 'Asia/Kolkata']
```

You could replace `datetime.datetime.now` with any date of your choice.

Same result using `pytz`:

```
import pytz

offset, match_offset = int(60*60*5.5), []

for z in pytz.all_timezones:
    off = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone(z)).utcoffset()
    if int(off.total_seconds()) == offset:
        match_offset.append(z)

print(match_offset)
# ['Asia/Calcutta', 'Asia/Colombo', 'Asia/Kolkata']
```

Note that `pytz` is more efficient in getting UTC offsets, however I'd prefer `dateutil` due to its better integration with the Python standard lib / `datetime` objects.